# onContext change in splunk using javascript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, splunk

i have a splunk app and now i want to add an oncontext change option with those app. i have 6 forms and each are having **separate,pulldowns/dropdowns**, 
could somebody can help me in creating a javascript*(actually i am confused whether it can be done with javascript)* to update all the dropdowns, if the context of any of the drop down changes, actualy all the dropdowns are populating same input i.e source filename. 
please help
Thank you
Sruthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this explains it well.](http://splunk-base.splunk.com/answers/70764/how-to-have-one-or-more-pulldown-or-textfield-selections-be-sticky-across-all-the-views-in-an-app) thanks for your assistance. append the javascript specified in t

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need custom javascript to accomplish this in Splunk.
You can do this in a Splunk Advanced XML View.
I would recommend having look at the examples in this app : http://splunk-base.splunk.com/apps/64805/splunk-dashboard-examples

Comment: thanks Damien, but what i want is not there in the splunk dashboard examples, i need something to connect two dashboards, some javascript/web interface to update all other dropdowns when one of the dropdown changes(the issue here is the dropdowns are in different dashboards not in same form)